# Recursively print all attributes, lists, dicts, etc of an object in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, object, recursion

Using Python 2.7.10, I have this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

#Do `sudo pip install boto3` first
import boto3
import json

def generate(key, value):
    """
    Creates a nicely formatted Key(Value) item for output
    """
    return '{}={}'.format(key, value)

def main():
    ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name="us-west-2")
    volumes = ec2.volumes.all()
    for vol in volumes:
        #print(vol.__str__())
        #print(vol.__dict__)
        print vol

     # vol object has many attributes, which can be another class object. 
     # For ex:
            #vol.volume_id),
            #vol.availability_zone),
            #vol.volume_type),

        # only process when there are tags to process
        # HERE: tags is another object which can contain a dict/list
        #if vol.tags:
        #    for _ in vol.tags:
        #        # Get all of the tags
        #        output_parts.extend([
        #            generate(_.get('Key'), _.get('Value')),
        #        ])


        # output everything at once.
        print ','.join(output_parts)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Is there a single function which can recursively print all the object's attributes using a single call? How can I print the values of val.xxxxx and val.tags.xxxx in one call.

I tried printing the object using `.__dict__` or `.__str__()` but it didn't help.

Comment: Just be really careful so you don't do things that triggers any code. I had a customer who managed to wipe half of their VMs doing "clever stuff" with the client.

Comment: Have you tried the pprint module?  Using that will require two lines of code since you have to import it, so it may not meet your requirements.

Comment: @PaulCornelius tried pprint but it didn't print anything recursively.

Comment: @Grimmy good catch.. but still, it'd be great to have such function

Comment: Interesting, since pprint's express purpose is to print recursive data structures.  Did you try pprint'ing an object's `__dict__`?

Comment: @PaulCornelius Actually it didn't print. I do see where a variable dict is already created, then it works fine for ex: https://pymotw.com/2/pprint/ here. But in my case, if you run the script which will fetch EBS volumes, printing all variables of a vol object by vol.xxx vol.yyy vol.someObject.xxx vol.someOtherObject.zzz didn't print using pprint. All I got is something like this: `{'_id': 'vol-baa1fafa', 'meta': ResourceMeta('ec2', identifiers=[u'id'])}` or `{'_id': 'vol-0fff354e1a8a99a21',
 'meta': ResourceMeta('ec2', identifiers=[u'id'])}`

Comment: I'm curious why it didn't work since it seems like exactly the tool you need.  An object's `__dict__` is itself an object, and is therefore "already created", or so I would think.  If the information you want to print isn't in `__dict__`, where is it?  Do these objects possibly use the `__slots__` feature?  Do they implement `__repr__`, which pprint will use if it's available.  That could terminate the recursion.

Comment: Well, so far I can't get all the info using pprint what I can get by using multiple for loops (looping into the object for ex: `tags` within the main `vol` object) and there are various similar nested objects within `vol` top level object (for ebs volumes) which I'm right now successfully able to get but with for loops. I was thinking, if I can just say pprint(vol) and it'll print everything in it recursively drilling down to each object level and showing all those attributes/fields using `pprint(vol)` or similar operation.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a function that you can drop into the **str** for your object.  You can also call it directly, passing in the object you wish to print.  The function returns a string that represents a nicely formatted walk of your object's contents.

Credit goes to @ruud from forum.pythonistacafe.com for coming up with this solution.

```
def obj_to_string(obj, extra='    '):
    return str(obj.__class__) + '\n' + '\n'.join(
        (extra + (str(item) + ' = ' +
                  (obj_to_string(obj.__dict__[item], extra + '    ') if hasattr(obj.__dict__[item], '__dict__') else str(
                      obj.__dict__[item])))
         for item in sorted(obj.__dict__)))


class A():
    def __init__(self):
        self.attr1 = 1
        self.attr2 = 2
        self.attr3 = 'three'


class B():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = A()
        self.attr10 = 10
        self.attrx = 'x'


class C():
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = B()


class X():

    def __init__(self):
        self.abc = 'abc'
        self.attr12 = 12
        self.c = C()

    def __str__(self):
        return obj_to_string(self)


x = X()

print(x)
```

Output:

```
<class '__main__.X'>
    abc = abc
    attr12 = 12
    c = <class '__main__.C'>
        b = <class '__main__.B'>
            a = <class '__main__.A'>
                attr1 = 1
                attr2 = 2
                attr3 = three
            attr10 = 10
            attrx = x
```